# Spring batch to process specific number of rows at a time

Tags: spring-batch

I have a scenario where in I have to get the business logic based on two consecutive rows in database . I am planning to use Spring Batch . I am not sure how to handle this scenario with Spring Batch .

Comment: Pls give an example with input and output

Comment: x1 y1  z1  a1 b1  ; x2  y2 z1 a1 b3 . scenario is based on y value i have to pick up values for other columns